# how to distinguish sent and received emails from pop3 server (usingPOCO c++)

Tags: c++, ssl, gmail, poco, pop3

I discovered that in retrieving a list of messages from gmail's pop3 server that everything gets pulled, read/unread, sent/recieved mail:

```
int idx, count;
Poco::Net::Context::Ptr pContext = new
    Poco::Net::Context (Poco::Net::Context::CLIENT_USE,
                        "", Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_NONE, 9, true);
pContext->enableExtendedCertificateVerification(false);
Poco::Net::SocketAddress addr("pop.gmail.com", p995);
Poco::Net::SecureStreamSocket sss(addr, pContext);
POP3ClientSession session(sss);

try
{
    vector<POP3ClientSession::MessageInfo>::const_iterator i;
    session.login(the_user.data(), the_pass.data());
    POP3ClientSession::MessageInfoVec messages;

    count = session.messageCount();
    session.listMessages(messages);

    for(idx = 0, i = messages.begin(); i != messages.end(); ++i, idx++)
    {
        MailMessage message;
        session.retrieveMessage((*i).id, message);
        // ..
    }
}
```

In a related post ([How to retrieve just unread emails using pop3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576354/how-to-retrieve-just-unread-emails-using-pop3)) someone mentioned "POP3 does not have the capibility to track whether messages are read or unread" - does this also apply to inbound & outbound messages?
If so, how do you distinguish message types? By parsing the message body?

I really could use a way to skip the sent mails, there are thousands and the program needs to run all night just to get to the inbound email.

Comment: Have you read a bit through the pop3 rfc(s) and what its capabilities are?

Comment: From when does POP3 server serves sent mail? Mail is sent using SMTP protocol

Comment: the question has absolutely nothing to do with sending mail (SMTP of course). gmail.com MTA returns all e-mail messages when getting a list of emails, whether sent or recieved. I don't know if that is standard POP3 behaviour. And no I haven't waded thru any RFCs, I'm waiting for the cliff notes edition to come out.